# Call reified function from non-reified one

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I've got a third-party service that exposes a reified extension function. I would like to wrap this service into an interface-implementation pair for easier testing and encapsulation reason.

The problem is that I can't use this function in my app, because compiler tells me that:

```
Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.
```

The structure is like following:

```
interface ThirdPartyService

inline fun <reified T> ThirdPartyService.execute(): T

interface Wrapper {
    fun <T> execute(): T
}

class WrapperImpl(private val thirdPartyService: ThirdPartyService) : Wrapper {
    override fun <T> execute(): T =
        thirdPartyService.execute()
}
```

In this case calling `thirdPartyService.execute()` causes a compiler issue I mentioned above.

Is there any way to overcome this issue? What does this `Use a class instead.` actually means?

Answer (score 2):

When you mark a type as reified, you're allowing it to be used explicitly in the function in places that it would normally be erased.

However the type `T` in your `Wrapper.execute` function here is *not reified* which means that it will be erased at runtime and therefore unable to be 'passed' to the `ThirdPartyService.execute` function.

You can read more about reified types [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).

---

In essence, the whole point of a function with a reified type is that it can use the type at runtime. So calling it without a concrete type doesn't make any sense and due to type erasure, a non-reified `T` is not a concrete type.